# wildfly 20 doesn't log with log4j. Which factors Can be involved for that?

Tags: log4j, wildfly

I have two environment development(local) and other QA environment, In the last is a cluster with two nodes.

The problem came with the deploy in QA environment I can't see the log in the server, but locally print console logging without problem.

I'm sure that module structure is the same in both environments, and my configure is in the classpath with xml file.

Which aspect can influence in this difference?

Local print logging console server and QA enviroment dont do it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this, I checked the server in the development environment, it's a domain configuration and for this reason it did not show the application log in the user wizard, due to application conditions only the applications write to the .log file, at start I was not allowed to check this domain log directory, but after I check this by command line my app log file is right there

I'll hope to help someone else